# Jquery finding specific indexOf

Tags: jquery

Hi I have this piece of code and what I want to happen is to, find all div "Complete!" then if it exist apply the css but only on "this" that was found and not the other ones that have a similar class, here's my code

```
var boxComplete = $('.profile-block p').text().indexOf('Complete!') > -1;
 if (boxComplete) {
 $('.profile-block p').parent().css('background', 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)');
}
```

The issue here is that it's applying the css to all other parent divs and I only want it on the one that was found

Comment: Show your HTML here...

Comment: your `boxComplet` is only going to return the text of first elemnt in collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) it out and then apply the css:

```
$('.profile-block p').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('Complete!') != -1;
}).parent().css('background', 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use `:contains` selector.

```
$('.profile-block p:contains(Complete)').parent().css('background','rgba(255,255,255,0.2)');
```

**[:contains selector API docs](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**